# Assigning a name to a pattern-matched item in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the following:

```
def f( a=(b,c,d) ):
  pass
```

But the interpreter complains that b is not defined when I do this. Is there a "Pythonic" way of getting the intended result? I know that I could do something like the following:

```
def f( (b,c,d) ):
  a = (b,c,d)
  pass
```

But I'd rather a solution that didn't require me to repeat myself. Any ideas?

**Edit for clarification**: What I am trying to do is have a function that can be called as follows:

```
f( (1,2,3) )
```

Then, within the body of the function, the following names are assigned:

```
a = (1,2,3)
b = 1
c = 2
d = 3
```

Comment: "Is there a 'Pythonic' way of getting the intended result?" That depends on what the intended result is. You might consider adding that information to your question. What do you expect the `a=(b,c,d)` in a function signature to do, besides set the default value of `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do precisely what you want. Moreover, tuple unpacking in formal function arguments is going the way of the dodo in python 3. The suggested replacement is to change

```
def f((a,b,c)):
    ...
```

to

```
def f(a_b_c):
    a,b,c = a_b_c
    ...
```

(That's the style of new argument name the 2to3 conversion script would generate; obviously you can use whatever sort of name you want.)

In your case, the simplest thing to do would be this:

```
def f(a):
    b,c,d = a
    ...
```

That has the minimum repetition.

Comment: Slightly better is to also name the variable something that implies what it is, such as `t` or `tuple_of_`.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a tuple; any sequence will do. I do think that indicating the quantity is vital if you intend to unpack to a fixed number of variables, so "tuple of" is often not sufficiently specific; something like `a_b_c` does this implicitly (and specifies the required order).

Comment: Or the other way around: `def f(a, b, c): abc = a, b, c...`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the function accept a tuple, why not have the caller unpack the tuple?

```
>>> def f(a, b, c):
        print a, b, c

>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> f(*t)
1 2 3
```

Otherwise consider the NamedTuple class.